# How best to implement a type-safe object query-expression parser in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, parsing, reduce

I have a complex object of a well defined type, and my app allows users to write a simple DSL to isolate values within it, kind of like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), and then apply assertions to those values (to create tests).  An example 'test' might be:

```
events.where(stage=read).logs[0] is "Hello world"
```

The app is a 'playground' tool that allows people to set up some configuration and then run it and see if it did what they expected. The testing feature allows them to assert the expected behaviour.

So, the challenge is to define a function whose signature is something like:

```
parseTestQuery(queryExpr: string, rootObject: ComplexType): ResolvedTargetValue
```

Currently I'm doing this by splitting the query expression on `.` and `[_]` and `reduce()`ing over the resulting token array, returning a *progressively deeper reference* at each callback.  But this means that the signature of the `reduce` is basically `(any): any`:

```
targetPath.split(/\.|(\[\d+\])\./).reduce((prev: any, thisToken: string): any => {
  // The callback handles array accessors like `[1]` and
  // aggregators like `.count()` etc but for simplicity...
  return prev[thisToken];
}, rootObject);
```

Can I do better than this?  How would you approach this kind of use case?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, every* time you use `any` - you should have used `unknown` instead.